# Automatic shutdown when the program is not used for a certain period of time

Tags: delphi, winapi, delphi-xe

We have a program and we are writing in Delphi XE. I have a problem :

If the program is not used for the duration that we set as the parameter, it should automatically return to the  input screen. So like windows, there must be a control like mouse and keyboard. Can you help me with this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Periodically call [`GetLastInputInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646302.aspx). This will return the tick count of the last input event. Then compare the difference between that input event's tick count and the current tick count against your timeout.

The downside of this approach is that you have to deal with the 49 day roll over issue with 32 bit Windows tick counts. As an alternative you might opt to install a system hook to monitor keyboard and mouse events. This will allow you to avoid the 49 day roll over issue, but is considerably more complex to implement.

Comment: A better solution would be to set up a timer with the application lock timeout. When it expires, calculate the difference between the current tick count and `GetLastInputInfo`. If the value is at least as large as the timeout, lock the application. Otherwise, restart the timer with the difference between the timeout and the elapsed time since the last input. The clock roll over isn't an issue either: If `GetTickCount` returns a value, that's smaller than the last input, the clock rolled over, and the calculation of the difference needs to be adjusted.

Comment: @IInspectable, in case of roll over will the calculation be: `Elapsed := (MAXDWORD - LastInput.dwTime) + T` (where `T := GetTickCount`)?

Comment: @zig: Almost. You'd have to add `1`, if you care about ultimate correctness. Whenever I'm not sure about interval calculations, I'd construct the simplest edge case. In this case I would assume `LastInput.dwTime` to return `MAXDWORD`, and `GetTickCount` being a single tick ahead, i.e. returning `0`. With your calculation `Elapsed` would be `0` when it should be `1` instead.